# How do I log the dates in the console as I am trying to do in this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, console

I am trying to console log Date, Req Method and Req URL like this. Is this wrong and how can I do this right?

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("${new Date()} - ${req.method} request for ${req.url}");
    next();
});

app.use(express.static("../static"));

app.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log("Serving static on 8000")
});
```

Currently the output is just

```
Serving static on 81
${new Date()} - ${req.method} request for ${req.url}
${new Date()} - ${req.method} request for ${req.url}
${new Date()} - ${req.method} request for ${req.url}
${new Date()} - ${req.method} request for ${req.url}
```

I am using express for node.js and a Linux(Fedora) machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use template literals, you need to replace the double quotes(`"`) with backticks(`` ` ``). After that, your `console.log` should look like this:

```js
console.log(`${new Date()} - ${req.method} request for ${req.url}`);
```

See more about template literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way for doing this in Linux is:

```
 console.log(new Date(), "-", req.method, "request for", req.url);
```

That should fix the issue.